# Is didSet on a @Binding file specific?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Essentially, I'm nesting `@Binding` 3 layers deep.

```
struct LayerOne: View {
    @State private var doubleValue = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        LayerTwo(doubleValue: $doubleValue)
    }
}

struct LayerTwo: View {
    @Binding var doubleValue: Double {
        didSet {
            print(doubleValue)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        LayerThree(doubleValue: $doubleValue)
    }
}

struct LayerThree: View {
    @Binding var doubleValue: Double {
        didSet {
            print(doubleValue) // Only this print gets run when doubleValue is updated from this struct
        }
    }

    var body: Some view {
        // Button here changes doubleValue
    }
}
```

Whichever struct I change `doubleValue` in is the one where the `didSet` will get run, so for example if I change it in `LayerThree` only that one will print, none of the others will.

I am able to watch for changes with `.onChange(of: doubleValue)` which will then get run when it changes but it's not making sense to me why `didSet` won't get run except on the struct where it's changed from.

**Is `@Binding` struct specific?**

Comment: All the layers are supposed to be `View`s, right?

Comment: @Sweeper All the layers are different views, yes. Basically only `LayerThree` will actually change the value though, the rest just pass it. I want to detect and do something after the change on `LayerTwo` which I'm able to with `.onChange` but it doesn't make sense why only that works.

Comment: What kind of code is this? why you are not conforming View?

Comment: @swiftPunk My bad, left that out... this is just simplified from my actual project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using property observers like `didSet` on values wrapped in `PropertyWrappers` will not have the "normal" effect because the value is being set inside the wrapper.

In SwiftUI, if you want to trigger an action when a value changes, you should use the `onChange(of:perform:)` modifier.

```
struct LayerTwo: View {
    @Binding var doubleValue: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        LayerThree(doubleValue: $doubleValue)
          .onChange(of: doubleValue) { newValue 
            print(newValue)
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotcha, so just like I thought... it's being set from within the struct that it's set, not up through the chain.

Answer (score 0):

To see why this happens, we can unveil the syntactic sugar of property wrappers. `@Binding var doubleValue: Double` translates to:

```
private var _doubleValue: Binding<Double>
var doubleValue: Double {
    get { _doubleValue.wrappedValue }
    set { _doubleValue.wrappedValue = newValue }
}

init(doubleValue: Binding<Double>) {
    _doubleValue = doubleValue
}
```

Whatever you do in `didSet` will be put after the line `_doubleValue.wrappedValue = newValue`. It should be very obvious why when you update `doubleValue` in layer 3, The `didSet` of `doubleValue` in layer 2 or 1 doesn't get called. They are simply different computed properties!

[swiftPunk's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70070601/5133585) works by creating a new binding whose setter sets the struct's `doubleValue`, hence calling `didSet`:

```
Binding(get: { return doubleValue }, 
        set: { newValue in doubleValue = newValue }
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                         this will call didSet in the current layer
```

Answer (score -1):

Now all working:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        LayerOne()
        
    }
    
}


struct LayerOne: View {
    
    @State private var doubleValue:Double = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            print("LayerOne:", doubleValue)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        LayerTwo(doubleValue: Binding(get: { return doubleValue }, set: { newValue in doubleValue = newValue } ))
    }
    
}

struct LayerTwo: View  {
    
    @Binding var doubleValue: Double {
        didSet {
            print("LayerTwo:", doubleValue)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        LayerThree(doubleValue: Binding(get: { return doubleValue }, set: { newValue in doubleValue = newValue } ))
    }
}




struct LayerThree: View  {
    
    @Binding var doubleValue: Double {
        didSet {
            print("LayerThree:", doubleValue) 
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(String(describing: doubleValue))
            
        Button("update value") {
            doubleValue = Double.random(in: 0.0...100.0)
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
}
```

**print results:**

> LayerOne: 64.58963263686678
>
> LayerTwo: 64.58963263686678
>
> LayerThree: 64.58963263686678

Comment: But why do you need to pass the binding that way? Shouldn't `didSet` get triggered regardless of where the binding is changed?

Comment: I think we cannot ask why or how, because it is Apple and closed source. For making didSet start working you need initialization for Binding.